# How to find the type of subfunctions with GHCI

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

Is it possible to find the type of functions defined in a `where` statement with GHCI ?

For example, considering this function :

```
myFunction a b c = case result of
                     2 -> ...
                            where
                                  subFunctA = ...
                     _ -> ...
                            where
                                  subFunctB = ...
                                  subFunctC = ...
```

The type of `myFunction` can be find with `:t myFunction`.

**Is it possible to find the types of `subFunctA`, `subFuncB` and `subFunctC` with GHCI ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [typed holes](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-13-type-of-local-function.html) if you have a new enough version of GHCi.

Basically, if you write an underscore in the code, the compiler will spit out an error message telling you what type that subexpression *should* have. In your example, just replace "`...`" with "`_`".

Answer (score 2):

No. GHCi does not have access to the source of its functions. This is true even if you defined the function yourself in GHCi, or in a source file.

As an alternative: since you have access to the source of the function you're wondering about, you can copy the functions into the global scope of your source file, compile them, and see what type GHC assigns them. I do this a lot. (Also, you can paste them into GHCi directly.) Once you've done this, you can call :t on them all you want. This does run the risk of producing more general types than the actual sub-functions have, but it could still help you.